# Android TextSwitcher size increasing on changing the font size in the display settings

Tags: android, android-layout, font-size

In my app, i have set fixed font size for all the text elements. And for a TextSwitcher that i am using, i am setting the font size like this.

```
altitudeSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.altitude);
        altitudeSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewFactory() {

            @Override
            public View makeView() {
                GradientColor gd = Gradients.AllGradients().get(2);

                TextView t = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                t.setTextSize(50);
                t.setTextColor(gd.getTextColor());
                return t;
            }
        });
```

But on changing the font size to huge in display settings, it increases a lot in size. How can i set the font size fixed ?

Answer (score 1):

That was a silly doubt. Found it out. I had to set the unit too like this `setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50);`